# Using AJAX when submitting forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm very new to form submission with AJAX and have been following many tutorials on it's use, however I cannot seem to get it working in my current scenario.

I have a modal with a form inside of it linked to a PHP script and some JQuery AJAX.

When i submit the form the page appears white, I'm fairly sure this is because of the conditional logic in my PHP script.

So, where I have `$stmt->rowCount()` and the conditional logic it returns nothing as the script does nothing at this point.

Can I link this logic to AJAX success or failure or do I have to return a boolean from my script?

I know this is probably considered a silly question but some clarity would be of great use.

Form

```
<form id="userForm" method="post" action="test/process_data.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder="E.g John" required>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Surname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="E.g Smith" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="company">Company:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company name">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Just take me to the partner</a>
  </form>
```

AJAX Script

```
<script>

      $("#userForm").submit(function(e) {
         var forename = $('#forename').val();
         var surname = $('#surname').val();
         var email = $('#email').val();
         var company = $('#company').val();

      $.ajax({
          url: "process_data.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
              "forename" : forename,
              "surname" : surname,
              "email" : email,
              "company" : company
          },
          success: function(data){
            $("#forename").val('');
            $("#surname").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#company").val('');

          }
      });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

      }


</script>
```

PHP Script to handle data

```
if (empty($_POST["forename"]) || 
    empty($_POST["surname"]) || 
    empty($_POST["email"]) ||
    empty($_POST["company"]))
    {

    }
    else{

        $forename = $_POST['forename'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $email_address = $_POST['email'];
        $company_name = $_POST['company'];
        $id = rand();
        $date_time = date('Y-m-d');


        try
            {
                // Construct the SQL to add a book to the database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (forename, surname, email_address, company_name, id, date_time)
                VALUES (:forename, :surname, :email_address, :company_name, :id, :date_time)";
                // Prepare the SQL and bind parameters
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':forename', $forename);
                $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email_address', $email_address);
                $stmt->bindParam(':company_name', $company_name);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
                $stmt->bindParam(':date_time', $date_time);
                $stmt->execute();

                // If the statement affected the database
                if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                {

                }
                else{

                }

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Use forms or AJAX, but don't use both together.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what? Why couldn't someone use AJAX to submit a form?

Comment: Your inputs are empty after the submit ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard You absolutely could, but you don't need the `<form>` tag and a `submit` button to do it. Those elements just add a level of redundancy that will never be used and add confusion to the code.

Comment: You could return a success or failure status flag that your frontend code reads to know if it was successful or not

Comment: In your `data` JS object - where are the `forename`, `surname`, `email` and `company` vars coming from? You might want `$('#forename').val()` for instance...

Comment: The problem you're having is that you never set the original values to be submitted, at least not in the code you posted.

Comment: If you were performing progressive enhancement @ScottMarcus you would be adding all of your JS *after* you had completed your baseline programming.

Comment: Simpler way to get all the data needed is `data:$(this).serialize(),`.  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: ^ that's a better solution

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok, yes, but are we really still writing code for people who have JavaScript turned off?

Comment: We always do @ScottMarcus. Many corporations are still sticking to their collective guns where JS is concerned. We also enhance existing sites where don't want to rewrite the underlying mark up.

Comment: @ScottMarcus did you honestly suggest that if a form gets sent with AJAX, then it shouldn't be in a `<form>` element? Keeping functionality intact for JS-disabled users is still a very important thing, as is semantics.

Comment: @rorymorris89 Yes, I did. Actually, let me clarify, what I meant was that the mechanism for submitting the form (the `method`, `action` and `submit` buttons) are unnecessary redundancies that cause code bloat and potential bugs because of duplication of code.I could invert your question and say, do you honestly believe that every AJAX call shouldn't have a `<form>` to go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use serialize() method on the form to define the data property in your ajax call. Also added error handling.

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "process_data.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  $("#userForm").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          //Successful
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
           if (!window.console) console = { log: function () { } };
           console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest), textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault();` before sending ajax request. Now when the form is done submitting you can do like this.

```
<script>

      $("#userForm").submit(function(e) {
         var forename = $('#forename').val();
         var surname = $('#surname').val();
         var email = $('#email').val();
         var company = $('#company').val();

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

      $.ajax({
          url: "process_data.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
              "forename" : forename,
              "surname" : surname,
              "email" : email,
              "company" : company
          },
          success: function(data){


          }
      });
$("#userForm").fadeOut(800, function()
{
     $(this)[0].reset();
}).fadeIn(800);


      }


</script>
```

Comment: also remove the `action` at the form

Comment: Yeah! I just looked at the `jquery` part! Thank you @xhulio.